# How to present Adyen checkout if i'm already presenting a controller?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uikit, adyen

i'm facing a problem, i'm using a tableview as sidebar to present certain controller from the app. When trying to preset Adyen checkout for payment getting an error that tells me i cannot use multi presenting, my question is, how can i fix this issue?

I was thinking to dismiss the sidebar after the button for checkout is pressed or to push the side bar and present the other controllers, but with no success or i didn't do it right.

Thank you!

This is the side menu button placed in MainViewController

```
public func setSideMenuButton()
    {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 65, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 160, width: 50, height: 50)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "side_menu_button").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!)
    {
        pauseEachExistingVideoPlayer()
        
        guard let sideMenuViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController") as? SideMenuViewController else { return }
      
        sideMenuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        sideMenuViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        present(sideMenuViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Presenting each index from the tabel

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
    
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: present( UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserProfileVC") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 1: present( UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SR_VideoLibrary") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 2: present( UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SR_Livestream") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 3: return
        case 4: return
        case 5: present( UIStoryboard(name: "VideoLibrary", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProjectsListVC") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 6: present( UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GetPremiumVC") as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        default:
            break
        } 
    }
```

This is how i dismiss the contrainer view and close the sidebar when tapped outside

```
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var modalView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = modalView
        {
            addTapGesture(target: view, action: #selector(dismissController))
        }
       
    }
    
    @objc private func dismissController()
    {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
extension SideMenuViewController {
    func addTapGesture(target: UIView, action: Selector, numberOfTaps: Int = 1) {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: action)
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTaps
        target.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        target.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}
```

[This is the side menu storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMTZH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that's a limitation in UIKit, a View Controller can present only one other ViewController.

So how I see it, you have two choices, either dismiss the already presented `SideMenuViewController` first, or make the `SideMenuViewController` present the Adyen view controller.

If you are using Adyen checkout SDK 3.5.0, there is a helper property added to every instance of a UIViewController that gets the top most presented view controller, use this property of the `MainViewController` -or any other view controller that would make sense to present the adyen checkout view controller- to present another one on top of it.

```
presenterViewController.adyen.topPresenter.present(secondPresentedVC, animated: true)
```

if you're using a version of the SDK in which this `adyen` helper is not present, you can implement an extension of UIViewController as follows:

```
extension UIViewController {

    var topPresenter: UIViewController {
        var topController: UIViewController = self
        while let presenter = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presenter
        }
        return topController
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thx for your time and answer, due the fact that i was wasting time on that problem, i gave up and used a colection view instead of table view and also gave up on storyboards, wrote it in MainViewControler, with that i could push some VC instead of presenting including the one with adyen, the only problem i have left is to figure it out how can I get some values from inside a func, inside AppDelegate and pass it to main view controller